# How to deal with Sedna via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xquery, nativexml, sedna

I have experienced for several years working on PHP with mySQL database ..

But now I have a home work to working on Sedna Native XML Database as DBMS with PHP, I went to Sedna hompage and download Sedna and try to working on it via commmand line, all this went on very nice way ..

I download PHP Driver, but I don't know what I can do with it, also I didn't find any documention on Sedna website or on internet that explain how to deal with Sedna via PHP !!

I want to know how I can deal with Sedna via PHP, like how I was deal with mySQL via PHP ..

Thanx in advance .. Louay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sedna PHP API package includes complete documentation. See `doc/php-api.pdf` file. It describes how to install API on Windows/Linux and describes each available method. Package also contains various examples (`examples` folder).

If you have some specific problem, please provide details.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but in doc folder I can't find php-api.pdf file :( If you have it can you upload it ?

Comment: It's definitely there. Check once again php-api-2.3.1.tgz/doc/ folder. NOT sedna/doc.

Comment: Aha, Finally I know how to open that unknown file which called php-api-2.3.1, thank you very much ..

Comment: You are welcome :) Let me know if you have any problems with Sedna. And don'f forget to accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Dear Shcheklein, I hope you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040473/update-insert-to-xml-by-sedna-via-php ... thank you