# Update insert to Xml by sedna via PHP

Tags: php, xml, sedna

I'm trying to insert new item to Xml file with this code

```
$conn = sedna_connect($host,$database,$user,$password);
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/ADEDB.xml';
$file = file_get_contents($path);
sedna_load($file, 'ADEDB');

sedna_tweak_opt(SE_OPTID_AUTOCOMMIT, false);
sedna_transact_begin();

sedna_execute('
UPDATE insert 
<Employee id="3">
 <name>Louay Hamada</name>
 <bday>21/01/1986</bday>
 <reg>Homs</reg>
 <adrs>Mazzeh</adrs>
</Employee>
into doc("ADEDB")/HRSystem/Employees
');

sedna_transact_commit();
sedna_tweak_opt(SE_OPTID_AUTOCOMMIT, true);
```

I know that my code would be worng, but I'm not found any document or examples that helps me to pass this problem :(

Comment: and which problem are you talking about?

Comment: I can't add this item to xml file !

Comment: Well, start with error tracking. Try to find out which error the system reports. If you have a support question concerning a specific product I normally suggest to contact the software vendor for your support options first *before* asking a programming question here. Just the standard trouble-shooting. In case it's a documentation or support issue, you most often find better resources there. You can later on answer your question here as well so to document how you made it.

Comment: But I don't get any errors when execute this code, and I think my question will be familiar with some people who working on Sedna and php, thank you for reply anyway.

Comment: Because you don't get any errors, you first need to take a look how to get errors. That's why I suggested you take the support route, e.g. reading documentation about *error handling* with that database client library and so on.

Comment: Maybe I don't mention that, but I also try if()..die(...sedna_error()..) to get any errors but no thing :)

Comment: Well if you don't get any error, there was *technically* no problem with the query. You probably do not check for errors when committing the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Sedna event logs (`SEDNA_HOME/data/event*.log` files). Have you checked them? Is there any error message?

Have you tried to run the same update statement via `se_term` (Sedna Terminal)? Try also to run `doc("ADEDB")/HRSystem/Employees` query to see if it returns anything at all.

Do you have namespaces in your document?

Comment: In Event log there is no errors. But with se_term and then query the document all new data are there !!! but if I opened xml file I can't find it.

Comment: Sedna is a database. It means it stores documents in some binary format which allows efficient XQuery execution, ACID transaction, etc ... See `SEDNA_HOME/{you-database-name}_data folder`. It contains *.sedata file. This is binary file which stores all documents of the database in a special internal representation. Some technical details you can find here http://www.slideshare.net/shcheklein/sedna-xml-database-system-internal-representation,  http://panda.ispras.ru/~grinev/mypapers/sedna.pdf

Comment: Okay, I understand it, but now what I can do to store new data into my XML file via above code. Thanx Shcheklein for help

Comment: For example, you can udpdate and then serialize your file either via terminal: `se_term -query "doc('ADEDB')" {database-name} > ADEDB-new.xml`, or via PHP itself.

Comment: Thank you again, but how I do that with PHP ?

Comment: Just run the same query `doc('ADEDB')` - see `05-query.php` example on how to run queries and print results.

Comment: I try what you say before I ask you, I doesn't work but after some work It now full fine :) Really I don't know how I can thank you :) Thank you very much.